# Nginx configuration for a nodejs app with SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

I have a node app running at

> localhost:8008/serviceName

This app is located in `/opt/myfolder/test/` where I have also generated in a certs folder, a `.pem` file and a `.cer` file signed by a CA.
I have also installed pm2 to help me run this server from an https endpoint.

I have a created a file called `service.conf` and symlinked it to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

This is what the `.conf` file looks like

```
    server {
        listen 443;

        server_name localhost

        root /opt/myfolder/test/public;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate    /opt/myfolder/test/certs/server.cer
        ssl_certificate_key    /opt/myfolder/test/certs/server.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;


    location @app {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8008;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
    }

}
```

In my Node.js app I have added the follwing:

```
var server = https.createServer({
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certs', 'server.pem')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certs', 'server.cer'))
    }, app);


 server = app.listen(8008,'localhost', function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Restarted nginx by : `sudo service nginx restart` and started the app using pm2 : `pm2 start app.js`

I can now access

> localhost:8008/serviceName

but am unable to access

> https://localhost:8008/serviceName.

```
Secure Connection Failed

The connection to localhost:8008 was interrupted while the page was loading.

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

I would like to know if there is something wrong in my configuration or is the app even being routed through nginx.
What am I missing ?

Comment: You've created https server and in the very next line you throw it away and create default http server (`app.listen(...);`)

Comment: Also, when you go to `localhost:8008` you bypass nginx completely. And if you want to use nginx you don't need your app to use HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing:

```
server = app.listen(8008,'localhost', function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

With:

```
server.listen(8008,'localhost', function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

fixed the issue.